# Get text between two integers Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var string = "454 blah bah 78";
```

How can I get the text between 454 and 78 when those two numbers are random? Like

```
var string = "randnumber blah bah randnumber2";
```

Note those numbers will always be integers and 2-3 characters long.

Comment: try `\d{2,3}\s(.*?)\s\d{2,3}` to match all text and Capture text in group 1. (if your random numbers are 2-3 digits)

Comment: Is there a predictable structure to the random numbers? Will they always be integers, will they always be between 2 and 3 characters? What have you tried, what went wrong, what difficulties have you had?

Comment: `/\d+([^\d]+)\d+/`

Comment: Yes they will always be integers and will be between 2-3 characters @DavidThomas

Comment: Then please add that, and any other useful information, to the question (click the [edit] link to edit and improve the question).

Comment: Can you tell us what a have you tried?it tells people that you somewhat struggled.

Comment: `Note those numbers will always be integers and 2-3 characters long.` This restricts the matches. Are you sure you want a max of 3 chars? Anyway, for that its `(?:\D|^)\d{2,3}\D+\d{2,3}(?=\D)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to select and remove the numbers from the string. The regexp that selects all numbers is `/[0-9]/`.
You can test regular expressions and practice with them in a variety of places online. Here is one: https://regex101.com/

So if your string is:

`var string = "454 blah bah 78";`,

you would want to:

`string = string.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');`.

The first part `string = string...` resets the var `string` as the result of calling the function `.replace...` on itself.

Note: this will take ALL of the numbers out of the string, so if there were  other numbers within that you wanted to keep, you'd have to work around it differently.

Comment: I would also trim the resulting string, like `string = string.replace(/[0-9]/g, '').trim();`

Answer (score 1):

Check this following code:

```
var reg = /^\d{2,3}([^\d]+)\d{2,3}$/
var a = "454 blah bah 78";
var txt = reg.exec(a)[1];
console.log(txt);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code

```
var temp = someString.split(' ');
var output = '';
if(temp.length > 2){ // min must have 1 word in between any 2 numbers...
    var number1 = parseInt(temp[0]);
    for(var i = 1; i < temp.length -1; i++){
        if(i > 1) output += ' ';
        output += temp[i];
    }
    var number2 = parseInt(temp[temp.length-1]);
}
console.log('String in between: '+output);
console.log('Number 1: '+number1);
console.log('Number 2: '+number2);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should look up the following functions:

```
split()
substr()
```